# overflow:auto breaks layout in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-float

Why is the `overflow:auto;` on `.pageContent` breaking the layout in Chrome and Firefox? It works great in Safari. How can I go about fixing it? I added it so the `clear:both;` on the `h2` would only clear the content and not the whole `.pageAttributes` div too.

[Here](http://wiki.justinzaun.com/buzz_aldrin) is the site.

It looks like its the `border-bottom` on `.selected` from the menu thats causing it. Still not sure why though.

**Update** - Test case [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNMH9/)

I've tried `overflow: visible;` but that breaks the `h2`.

HTML

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="pageAttributes">
        .pageAttributes
    </div>
    <div class="pageMenu">
        <div class="button">View</div>
        <div class="button selected">Edit</div>
        <div class="button">Talk</div>
        <div class="search">Search:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="searchItem">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
        <h2>header</h2>
        .pageContent
        <div class="pageFooter"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.page {
    width: 1010px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;

}

.pageAttributes {
    float: left;
    width: 245px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.pageMenu {
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

.pageMenu .button {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1px;
    height: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pageMenu .button.selected {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    cursor: default;
}

.pageMenu .search {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -1px;
    height: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: default;
}

.pageContent {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.pageContent h2 {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to change it to `overflow:visible;`? I checked in Chrome and Firefox and seems to work.

Comment: @cHao - Test case added (code and jsfiddle)
@maqjav - That breaks the `h2` clear.

Comment: Let's make some tests. What if you move the pageMenu div on top of pageAttributes div?

Comment: @maqjav - pageContent looks OK, pageAttributes shifts down, under the menu

Comment: the problem are the floats in .button why do you float everything? can you position the boxes with absolute and relative?

Comment: @Justin808. With the change we did, you only have to remove the top margin of .pageAttributes h1 for the text "Personal". Then it looks the same.

Comment: @caramba - on the site, there are 2 css, layoutCommon and layoutLeft. I can switch layoutLeft with layoutRight and everything flips. floats make this easy to do.

Comment: @maqjav - http://jsfiddle.net/LNMH9/4/ <-- works in Chrome, in FF it's much more broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
#articleSections{
    float: left;
}
```

and remove the `overflow: auto;` from `.pageContent`

Comment: This was the closest. I added a `.pageContentInner` and added the `overflow: auto;` to it. Would have thought of it without this one.

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems to be a floating problem wich I could not clear between the .button(s) and the search input. so positioning could be a solution like this

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LNMH9/3/

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.page {
    position:relative;

    width: 1010px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.pageAttributes {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 245px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.pageMenu {

    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

.pageMenu .button {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1px;
    height: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pageMenu .button.selected {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    cursor: default;
}

.pageMenu .search {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -1px;
    height: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: default;
}

.pageContent {
    position: absolute;
    width:748px;
    border: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.pageContent h2 {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
    clear: both;
}
</style>
<div class="page">
    <div class="pageAttributes">
        .pageAttributes
    </div>
    <div class="pageMenu">
        <div class="button">View</div>
        <div class="button selected">Edit</div>
        <div class="button">Talk</div>
        <div class="search">Search:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="searchItem" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
        <h2>header</h2>
        Lorem ipsum 
        <div class="pageFooter"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```